# Match a string to multiple regex patterns and return the group number

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with regular expressions in Java using `Matcher` class

Here is a description of what I have:

I have a multiple regex separated by pipes.
I have to get the group of the words that matches one of the regular expressions.

this is the `pattern`variable :

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "^TDXF.*\\w+-(\\d+)(\\.\\d+)+_(\\d+\\.)+\\d+|^TD.{3}([0-9]).{4}$|^.*_.*-.*-([0-9]*)\\..*\\..*\\..*$");
```

and this method is used to return the group number  associated to the word.

```
private static String getGroup(String gp) {
    String g= "";
    if (gp== null) {
        return g;
    }

    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(gp);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
 g= matcher.group(1) != null ? matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(2);
    }
    return g;
}
```

I wrote a unit test to test if it works for this string for example : `TD91160152` but it failed.

```
 @Test
public void testGroup() {
    Assert.assertEquals("6", this.getStep("TD91160152"));
    Assert.assertEquals("2", this.getStep("TDXF-tv-2.5.10.1_0.0.0.0"));
    Assert.assertEquals("6", this.getStep("TD91160118_SF11043004"));

    Assert.assertEquals("3", this.getStep("TDXF_sih-tv-3.4.12.1_7.21.3.1"));
    Assert.assertEquals("5", this.getStep("TD20_sih-tv-5.2.20.1"));
    Assert.assertEquals("5", this.getStep("TD30_sih-tv-5.15.8.1"));
}
```

`TD91160152` matches this pattern `^TD.{3}([0-9]).{4}$` and it should return `6` as a matcher.group(1) number : [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/0JO0WR/4)

I don't know why it fails and return null as a group number.
I don't think that it's related to overlaps between the regex.

I tried to remove the other patterns and only put

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "^TD.{3}([0-9]).{4}$");
```

and it worked.. I don't know why when I add the other regex it returns null.

can anyone help me on this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to every one who toke time to read and think with me for a solution.
Hopefully I found a solution. I ended up by separating the patterns and the test if the word matches the pattern. (maybe ther's a confusion somewhere when using the iterator `|`)

```
private static Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^TDXF.*\\w+-(\\d+)(\\.\\d+)+_(\\d+\\.)+\\d+");

private static Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^TD.{3}([0-9]).{4}$");

private static Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("^.*_.*-.*-([0-9]*)\\..*\\..*\\..*$");

private static String getGroup(String gp) {
    String g = "";
    if (gp== null) {
        return g;
    }

    final Matcher matcher1 = p1.matcher(gp);
    final Matcher matcher2 = p2.matcher(gp);
    final Matcher matcher3 = p3.matcher(gp);

    if (matcher1.matches()) {
        g= matcher1.group(1) != null ? matcher1.group(1) : matcher1.group(2);
    }
    if (matcher2.matches()) {
        g= matcher2.group(1) != null ? matcher2.group(1) : matcher2.group(2);
    }
    if (matcher3.matches()) {
        g= matcher3.group(1) != null ? matcher3.group(1) : matcher3.group(2);
    }
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your regex, looks like its fine. Maybe you need other function or flags in your regex expression? 
Screenshots i made [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html)

[Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MASVr.png)

[Matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC4DE.png)

[Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62bCJ.png)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, did you test `getGroup()` method? did it return a value?
My problem is that it's not returning a group value, it's returning ` null`instead.

Comment: @pietà , sorry, but i didn't. At the moment i don't have java and used only online version of java regex engine. It shows captured 4th group, with value 6

Answer (score 0):

The value `TD91160152` matches the second part of your regex but the group is the 4th group in your total regex. So you need to use `getGroup(4)` to get `6`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Ff {
    static String part1="^TDXF.*\\w+-(\\d+)(\\.\\d+)+_(\\d+\\.)+\\d+$";
    static String part2 = "^TD.{3}([0-9]).{4}$";
    static String part3 = "^.*_.*-.*-([0-9]*)\\..*\\..*\\..*$";
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(part1+"|"+part2+"|"+part3);


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Matcher m=pattern.matcher("TD98760452");
        if(m.matches())
        {
            for (int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++)
                System.out.println(m.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
null
null
null
6
null
```